# manage.py not present in Django project

Tags: python, django

I'm just starting the Django tutorial. On running the command:

```
$django-admin.py startproject mysite
```

the mysite project is created, but there's no manage.py file under mysite/

I tried to get the verbose output:

```
$django-admin.py startproject -v 3 mysite 
/home/pratik/Source/Numerical/ETS/etsproxy/enthought/__init__.py:7: DeprecationWarning: enthought namespace imports are deprecated
  DeprecationWarning)
Rendering project template files with extensions: .py
Rendering project template files with filenames: 
Creating /home/pratik/Projects/django_learn/mysite/mysite/__init__.py
Creating /home/pratik/Projects/django_learn/mysite/mysite/urls.py
Creating /home/pratik/Projects/django_learn/mysite/mysite/settings.py
Creating /home/pratik/Projects/django_learn/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
```

I'm using the latest Django source from the [git repository](https://github.com/django/django)

Any ideas on what might be wrong? I'll update this post with more information as I go along.

More Information:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Dec 26 2010, 22:31:48) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Edit: It seems that manage.py is just a wrapper around django-admin.py, so now I can 
at least go ahead with the tutorial

Edit2: I tried with the stable 1.4.3 version as well, but still no luck

```
$ django-admin.py version
1.4.3
```

Edit3: Here is the output of `tree`:

```
$ tree
.
`-- mysite
    `-- mysite
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- settings.py
        |-- urls.py
        `-- wsgi.py

2 directories, 4 files
```

Comment: Which `django.VERSION` are you using?

Comment: @AndyHayden: current github repo shows 1.6.0 alpha. Seems kind of bleeding-edge for someone doing the tutorial.

Comment: @PeterRowell I tried with the stable 1.4.3 release as well. Didn't make a difference

Comment: To be clear in your current working directory can you run: `tree` and provide the output?

Comment: @sigmavirus24 I edited the original post with the output of tree

Comment: @pratikm did you delete mysite before recreating it with django-admin?

Comment: Yes! I did do that many times...is that what's causing the error?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a virtualenv and doing the installation there?

Answer (score 2):

can you just create your manage.py manually?

put this code inside:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":

    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "{{ project_name }}.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

source:
https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/conf/project_template/manage.py